# Connect SDRAM to STM32

Tags: memory-usage, memory, sram, stm32

Well, first of all hello to everything and thanks for reading my question. I am designing a board with STM32F730R8T6 MCU, and I want to connect MT48LC16M16A2P-6A to it which is 4MB SDRAM chip. The connections are pretty basic from what I saw, the thing is, how can I access that memory from my MCU? I mean there is a library or something to use it? and, if someone can send me an example schematic, to connect the memory I would appreciate it. Greetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you have to choose variant with FMC module (Flexible Memory Controller) with SDRAM support - that means you have to use 144pin version STM32F730**Z**8. The 100pin version does have FMC but doesn't support SDRAM.

After resolving this issue, it should be about configuring FMC module for using SDRAM (in STM32CubeMX for example) and the RAM will be available at some memory location according to the MCUs memory layout.